# How to replace a key inside a nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this list

```
   {
   '0': { id: 'id3', name: 'Capitan America', job: 'superHero' },
   '1': { id: 'id4', name: 'Spider-man', job: 'Pro footballer' }
  }
```

And i want to change my keys to the id value like this:

```
 {
   id3 : { id: 'id3', name: 'Capitan America', job: 'superHero' },
   id4 : { id: 'id4', name: 'Spider-man', job: 'Pro footballer' }
  }
```

this is what i have tried in my code where in my fetch items i transform an array of objects into an object of objects and when i transform into one object of object my keys stayed like the index of the array:

```
    fetchItems() {
                       
         const objectified = Object.assign({},this.list)
         return objectified;     
        }
```

Comment: Map the `Object.keys()` of the original into a new object.  Or the `Object.values()` since you don't care what the original key was.

Comment: Also, very important thing here, you don't have an array or list.  You have an object.  `{}` denotes an object.  `[]` denotes an array.  You do not have an array here.

Comment: That's not a list, that just a plain object where the keys happen to be strings with numbers in them. You can use an `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(yourthing).map(...))` to turn your object into a new object with different keys.

Comment: All the answers miss the point that the object that contains numbers as properties, is the result of the code in the question, and the OP should fix that code, instead of adding more code.

Comment: @MohammadDehghan - good catch. Updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `Object.assign` to assign an array to an object, indices of the array will become properties of the assigned object. The best way to construct your desired object is to build it manually.

Modify your `fetchItems` as below:

```
function fetchItems() {
    const result = {};
    for (const item of list)
        result[item.id] = item;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: All the other answers try to just provide a somehow complex code, that fixes the thing *after creating the wrong thing*, without fixing the OP's mistake, without instructing the OP in the right direction and teaching him something. Sorry guys. This is not good.

Comment: Thank you for the tip appreciated sir

Answer (score 0):

Map the array to pairs of `[id, object]`, and then convert to an object using `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 'id3', name: 'Capitan America', job: 'superHero' },
  { id: 'id4', name: 'Spider-man', job: 'Pro footballer' }
]

const result = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(o => [o.id, o]))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do what you are asking by stepping over each property, building a new object.

```
var objA = {
    '0': { id: 'id3', name: 'Capitan America', job: 'superHero' },
    '1': { id: 'id4', name: 'Spider-man', job: 'Pro footballer' }
};

function transform(obj) {
    var newObj = {};
    for(p in obj) { newObj[obj[p].id] = obj[p]; }
    return newObj;
}

var objB = transform(objA);
console.log(objB);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.entries` and iterate through the key-value pairs with `.reduce`

```js
const data = {
  0: { id: "id3", name: "Capitan America", job: "superHero" },
  1: { id: "id4", name: "Spider-man", job: "Pro footballer" },
}

const res = Object.entries(data).reduce(
  (acc, el) => ({ ...acc, [el[1].id]: el[1] }),
  {}
)

console.log(res)
```